# number of symmetries of an arbitrary graph

Tags: group-theory, graph-theory, symmetric-groups, algebraic-graph-theory, computational-algebra

Given an (undirected) graph `G`, is there way to (approximately) estimate the order of `Aut(G)`-- i.e., the number of permutations with the same adjacency matrix (up to permutation)?
How about the orbits?

Is there any literature on computational algebraic graph theory that can be helpful here?

Comment: Almost all graphs have no nontrivial automorphisms, Chris Godsil's algebraic graph theory is a good start to the topic. You'll have to be more specific if you want to know more.

Comment: But the graph is not random. I was hoping there are some computational methods, such as monte-carlo/search techniques to estimate this number efficiently. Especially since the problem is not known to be NP-complete.

Comment: If you're dealing with concrete graphs then you can use the program nauty to compute the automorphism group. If you are dealing with a specific class of graphs then maybe you can prove they have some automorphisms by the way you construct them.

Comment: Thanks, I was aware of naughty, but my objective requires obtaining a `very rough` estimate faster than these software packages.

Comment: Then I suppose it would be good if you could describe your graphs by a formal construction.